# Meaning of "prostrate bowed but not believing"

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

I struggle to understand this line in [G. Hansard's song Bird of Sorrow](http://www.lyricsmode.com/lyrics/g/glen_hansard/bird_of_sorrow.html#!):

> You prostrate bowed but not believing

Can you please help?

Comment: What don't you understand?  Do you know what 'prostate' and 'bow' mean?

Comment: It's an oddball *poetic* usage that might be more "naturally" expressed using a postpositive adverbial form: *You bow **prostrately*** (= in a prostrate manner). Except that in practice we don't normally use that particular adverb.

Comment: Thank you. However, I am more after the meaning. How would you explain the meaning of "bow prostrately"? I need to translate it into my language (Czech).

Comment: Well, are we speaking about this kind of gesture? http://kaheel7.com/eng/images/stories/q23.JPG

Comment: Venda: As @John says, *use a dictionary*. Where you'll find, for example: [1 - (Often reflexive) To lie flat or facedown. 2 - To throw oneself down in submission (also figuratively).](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prostrate) Prostrating oneself could be seen as a "gesture", but we normally reserve that noun for ways one might move one's ***hands***, not one's whole body.

Comment: As written, it doesn't make any sense.  Maybe if we wrote it like this: "You're prostrate, bowed but not believing" . . . ?

Comment: [This](http://www.metrolyrics.com/bird-of-sorrow-lyrics-glen-hansard.html) says it's "Your prostrate bowed would not be leavin'" - which still doesn't make sense, but makes a very different not-sense from your version. [This](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/glenhansard/birdofsorrow.html) says "you're prostrate bowed, but not believing", which makes more sense.

Comment: How about "You're prostrate; bowed but not believing"? Then it would mean that you are face-down flat on the ground (prostrate, as opposed to supine), forced into a position not of your volition (bowed) and at the same time denying it (but not believing).

Ah, punctuation, you are so underestimated.

[EDIT]: Oh, snailplane already made that interpretation.

Comment: I have added a link to the song lyrics and corrected an editing mistake that @Peter introduced ("your" instead of "you"). It is very important to link the original source of the sentence you're asking about in these situations. I realize that it should be "you prostrate yourself, bowed but no believing", but because it's a lyric, I feel like some liberties may have been taken to make the song flow better than if it were 'you're pros**trate**' which sounds awfully close to 'your pros**tate**'...

Comment: You might also want to ask this question on the new [Literature SE](http://literature.stackexchange.com/) (beta), where they might be able to give you more "interpretive" help that's not so on-topic here (but is [on-topic there](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/questions/67/are-songs-and-poems-on-topic), at least so far).

Answer (score 1):

> You prostrate bowed but not believing
>   [which is significantly different from the lyric on the site; my answer concerns the phrase as given above]

This is a noun phrase, not a sentence.

**you** is the noun at the head of the phrase.

**prostrate** is an adjective, modifying **you**.

**bowed** is the past-participle of the verb **bow**, used adjectivally, modifying **you**

**but not believing**  the present-participle **believing**, from the verb **believe**, is again used adjectivally, modifying **you**.

We might use a noun-phrase such as this one either as the subject or the object of a verb.

> This picture of the mob of supplicants before the emperor-god of the
>   planet Xenon shows **you, prostrate, bowed, but not believing**.
>
> **You, prostrate, bowed, but not believing**, cursed the pious intergalactic
>   bastards.

Comment: A nice deconstruction of the mechanics, but you failed to answer the question of what it means.

Comment: Not true.  I indicate the grammatical role of the words and phrase, and any dictionary could tell the OP what the individual words mean.  Anything beyond that would be "lit-crit", which is off-topic.  And in any case, the phrase in the question doesn't match the lyric in the linked site.

Answer (score 0):

A typical "bow" is slightly bent forward and indicates obedience or reverence.  If you bowed so much that you were prostrate on the ground (face down, outstretched) it would imply that you are "all in" in your dedication and submission to the target of the bow.

Here is the full line from the song, with proper usage of `you're`:

> You've given over to self-deceiving, you're prostrate bowed, but not believing

This indicates to me the author is accusing the subject of being a spectacular liar.  His actions show that he believes whole heartedly, yet he does not.  He might be putting on a show for others around him so that they think he is a devout believer, but he's even deceived himself, as the author states at the beginning of the line.

This is a common theme in religion and all of humanity.  Our actions deceive us.

Comment: I found a different set of lyrics that say the line is "You prostrate bowed" instead of "you're prostrate bowed" (no-one is putting any commas in there to help us!) Where did you find the entire line of the song?

Comment: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Tqw4trqgtbu4e5vpj3uf5ieeipu?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-lyrics) lists it as "Your prostrate bowed".  Also, https://youtu.be/uIGCpWi5dIs?t=104

Comment: It does sound like he's saying "you're prostrate bowed" in the video - 'your' seems obviously wrong.

Comment: "you are prostrate bowed" would not be idiomatic. The idiomatic version would be "You are bowed prostrate" or "You are prostrate, bowed..." or simply "You are prostrate".

Answer (score 0):

I think the best synonym here for the highly poetic *prostrate bowed* would be the Chinese loan word *kowtowed*.

"to touch the forehead to the ground while kneeling, as an act of worship...."

http://www.dictionary.com

This would not maintain the meter in the poem, but might be clearer in projecting the meaning.

Answer (score -1):

It means **hypocrisy**. **prostrate** is an act everybody can see it , but believing is in the heart no one can see , except for God .